# Architecture problem

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

I want to do a method that will replace this-

```
 for (var i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
        {
            ...... // code that should run every second 

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

So I wrote the following method:

```
  public static void DoEverySecond(int seconds, Action action)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
        {
            action.Invoke();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

and now every time that I want to do something every second I can just call -

```
 HelperClass.DoEverySecond(5, () =>
        {
            Console.Write("Hellow")
        });
```

**the problem is that when the action contains return, the loop doesn't stop.
It's just getting out from the action and continues to the next iteration.**

```
  HelperClass.DoEverySecond(5, () =>
        {
              return;
        });
```

Comment: OMG - I didn't know that. I always thoughs lambda expressions are implemented as independend methods and not as simple code injections in a parent method..

Comment: I'm glad you've learn something new today :)

Comment: Not sure this will work, but have you tried *break* or *goto*?

Comment: @oleksii: it will not even compile, let alone work

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) instead of Action and then change your code to something like:

```
  public static void DoEverySecond(int seconds, Func<bool> action)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < seconds; i++)
        {
            if(!action.Invoke())
            {
                return;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

And then have your function return false if your loop should break

Comment: Thanks userx.

But I would like that the DoEverySecond method will accept any kind of code and not only with Boolean return. This reduces the method generically.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer @userx's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355227/architecture-problem/6355421#6355421).

However, another option would be to throw  an exception inside the invoked action when you want to exit the loop. Catch the exception in `DoEverySecond` and `break` out of the loop. Be aware of the [performance implications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891217/how-expensive-are-exceptions-in-c) of doing this if it is a common occurrence.

Comment: I hate to say it (because it certainly can be expensive), but this is probably more the ".NET way" to implement it (e.g. define a custom exception like 'BreakDoEverySecondException' and catch only that exception in DoEverySecond), almost like a TimeoutException.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in the c#, but in your code.
Of course, them the action returns, next lines of code woudn't execute.
You should rewrite your code to no use of return statement:

```
    HelperClass.DoEverySecond(5, () =>
    {
        bool notReturn = true;
        // some code to define, return or not
        if (notReturn)
        // some other code here
    });
```

Comment: What's the point of having an `if()` statement with an expression which always evaluates to true?

Comment: It's not always evaluates to true. Get some imagination. I meant that the `notReturn` variable defines, are we continue method execution or not. I've updated the answer