# LINQ Single() Exception for 0 or multiple items

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have some `IEnumberable` collection of items. I use `.Single()` to find a specific object in the collection.

I choose to use `Single()` because there should only ever be one specific item. However, if one doesn't exist, then I need to create it and add it to the collection.

My problem is that `Single()` throws the same error if there is no item matching the predicate or if there are multiple items. My idea was to put the `Single()` call inside of a try and catch the exception, add the item, and then continue. However, since both scenarios throw the `InvalidOperationException`, how can I tell if its due to no items or multiple items?

I know I can use `First()` but that doesn't enforce the idea that there should be only one (without doing extra work).

I could also use `Count()` before the `Single()` call, but that just seems to undermine the point of `Single()`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

What you want is `SingleOrDefault()`

The "or default" actually means it returns null (for reference types) or whatever the default would be for a non-reference type. You'll need to new-up an object to take its place.

Comment: ...and if you want to chain null check, may use something like this http://napoleonss.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/my-check-null/.
Works for defaults on types

Comment: Well, it returns the default value for the element type. That's null for reference types, but obviously not for non-nullable value types...

Comment: @JonSkeet You are correct. I assumed he was talking about a reference type though.

Comment: @DigitalD: Yes, probably in this case. It's just that your second sentence makes it sound like you'd have named the method `SingleOrNull`, which wouldn't have been reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't recommend using the try/catch in this scenario, because using exceptions to make logical decisions is resource expensive.

I would recommend using `SingleOrDefault()`, and check if the result is null.  If it is.  Do your creation.

Comment: "resource expensive" - is somewhat of an antiquated/incorrect view. See the Rico Mariani link provided here. http://stackoverflow.com/q/891217/16391. I do agree that using exceptions to make logical decisions is a poor design choice.

Answer (score 1):

SingleOrDefault will throw an exception when there is more than one item in the set. You will have to check for the size beforehand manually.

```
var singleItem = list.Count() == 1 ? list.Single() : null;
```

Maybe it's best to just make your own extension function.