# How to catch exception from a constructor in a derived class with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, constructor

I was wondering how to catch an exception from a constructor in a derived class with C#. Something as such:

```
public class MyClassA
{
    public MyClassA()
    {
        //Do the work
        if (failed)
        {
            throw new Exception("My exception");
        }
    }
}

public class MyClassB : MyClassA
{
    public MyClassB()
    {
        //How to catch exception from a constructor in MyClassA?
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that this isn't possible.

Comment: It may be just me, but I have always tried to avoid constructors doing "work". I think it is quite unusual behavior and could prove troublesome for developers who are not as knowledgeable with the codebase.

Comment: Unlike some other OOP languages, throwing exceptions from a C# constructor has well defined behavior.  Catching it is well defined too, it requires a try/catch around the *new* operator.  So at least one level up from where you hope to put it.  Catching it in the derived class won't work of course, that's a house of cards without a basement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not even try to figure out how to do this. If the base class constructor is throwing an exception, it means the base class is in a bad state. If the base class is in a bad state, it means the derived class is in a bad state. The point of a constructor is to get an object into a useable state. It failed. Get out!

Comment: You have it backwards.  In this case the base class is constructed just fine, but the derived class throws.  This is typically  a problem with Disposable objects where the base class is expecting to be disposed (because its constructor worked) but it won't be because a constructor in a derived class failed.

Comment: @Yaur: What are you talking about? Read the code: `MyClassB : MyClassA`.

Comment: My bad. mistook this for a more interesting problem

Answer (score 1):

1) A workaround: create a factory method in the derived:

```
class MyClassB : MyClassA
{
    public static MyClassB Create()
    {
        try
        {
            return new MyClassB();
        }
        catch
        {
            // try to handle
        }
    }
}
```

<s>2) or create a similar in the base and don't throw in the constructor but in the method instead:</s>

```
class MyClassA
{
    public static MyClassA Create()
    {
        MyClassA x = new MyClassA();
        if (x.Failed)
            throw new Exception();
        return x;
    }
}
```

3) or provide an overridable strategy to handle failed state:

```
class MyClassA
{
    public MyClassA
    {
        if (failed)
            OnFail();
    }

    protected virtual void OnFail()
    {
         throw new Exception();
    }
}

class MyClassB : MyClassA
{
    protected override void OnFail()
    {
        // don't throw
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you inherit from a base class with factory method (your option #2)?

Comment: +1 for #3. I have a generic base factory class that uses reflection to instantiate a concrete class from a name. By overriding a virtual method on the derived concrete factory classes, I can implement custom error handling when something goes wrong in the base class.

Answer (score 1):

i would handle it like this i think

```
public class MyClassA
{

    protected bool test;
    public MyClassA()
    {
        //Do the work
        if (true)
        {
            test = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}

public class MyClassB : MyClassA
{
    public MyClassB() 
    {
        if (base.test)
        {
            //How to catch exception from a constructor in MyClassA?
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: throwing exceptions is very expensive. This is a better approach

Comment: @HasTaiar: This is not true. Even in C++. [In C# exceptions are not expensive at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891217/how-expensive-are-exceptions-in-c)

Comment: Thanks abatishchev, that 's still controversial even in the link u provided.. Cheers :)

Comment: I would disagree.  If your base class can't be constructed then something is majorly wrong with the code.  I would move the logic to build up the internal state of an object to a method call and leave the base construction to just that.  This gives you better control over your code.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the same problem with static method:

```
public class PdfReaderExtended : PdfReader
{
    public PdfReaderExtended(string filename) : base(filename)
    {

    }

    public static PdfReaderExtended CreateInstance(string filename)
    {
        var name = Path.GetFileName(filename);
        try
        {
            return new PdfReaderExtended(filename);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ClientException("Oops");
        }
    }
}
```