# Wait for request of CancellationToken cancellation

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

How can I pause the executing until the cancellation is requested?

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task.Run(() =>
{
    // Wait for the Cancel...

    Console.WriteLine("Canceled!");
});

Console.ReadKey();

cts.Cancel();

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Seems extrange to require that something is cancelled to continue but maybe it is just the example used in the question.

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia is more of an experiment, it is not production code, of course.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `CancellationTokenSource` uses a `ManualResetEvent` internally and you can just wait for the exposed `WaitHandle` to pause the execution until it is set.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task.Run(() =>
{
    WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { cts.Token.WaitHandle });

    Console.WriteLine("Canceled!");
});

Console.ReadKey();

cts.Cancel();

Console.ReadKey();
```

This is the WaitHandle defined in the `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_kernelEvent, mre, null) != null)
{    
    ((IDisposable)mre).Dispose();
}

// There is a ---- between checking IsCancellationRequested and setting the event.
// However, at this point, the kernel object definitely exists and the cases are:
//   1. if IsCancellationRequested = true, then we will call Set()
//   2. if IsCancellationRequested = false, then NotifyCancellation will see that the event exists, and will call Set().
if (IsCancellationRequested)
    m_kernelEvent.Set();

return m_kernelEvent;
```

And the `Token` just returns the handle from the source (has an internal variable referencing it).

Another option is to register the `Token` callback and use your own `ManualResetEvent`:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task.Run(() =>
{
    var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    var registration = cts.Token.Register(() => mre.Set());

    using (registration)
    {
        mre.WaitOne();

        Console.WriteLine("Canceled!");
    }
});

Console.ReadKey();

cts.Cancel();

Console.ReadKey();
```

Examples: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/05/22/net-4-cancellation-framework/

Comment: In the link provided, it uses WaitAny instead of WaitOne on the handle as @KooKiz suggested, do you know why are they using a different approach?

Comment: In the link there are both WaitOne/WaitAny. It does not matter if you use WaitOne or WaitAny on an array with one WaitHandle. It is the same.

Comment: @user4388177 in the link is waiting on two handles, here you can use `WaitOne`, I just copied the example from the post and modified it without "refactoring".

Answer (score 26):

You can use the `WaitHandle` to wait synchronously:

```
static void Main()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Wait for the Cancel...

        cts.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne();

        Console.WriteLine("Canceled!");
    });

    Console.ReadKey();

    cts.Cancel();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

That said, "blocking a thread until something is cancelled" is a very uncommon scenario, so it's possible that you're using the wrong tool for this job. If you need to wait on something (not specifically a cancellation), you can use a `TaskCompletionSource` instead. If you need to react to a cancellation, you can use `CancellationToken.Register` to attach a callback (and therefore avoid blocking a thread).

Comment: In the link that @uno provided, it uses WaitAny instead of WaitOne on the handle, do you know why are they using a different approach?

Comment: @user4388177 In the link, they use `WaitHandle.WaitAny` when they need to wait on multiple handles. If you have only one, then `WaitOne` does the trick

Comment: They are actually waiting just one event wrapped into an array, sounds odd to me, but being from the Microsoft pfxteam blog makes me thing it might be somehow the right thing to do.

Comment: @user4388177 Are we reading the same article? I see `WaitHandle.WaitAny(new [] {wh, token.WaitHandle}); `  That's two handles

Comment: `TaskCompletionSource` is the way to go. Since you want to 'cancel' or stop the execution. You are basically completing the operation.

Answer (score 13):

The most concise way is probably this:

```
try { await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cts.Token); }
catch (OperationCanceledException) { } // Ignore this exception
```

This approach relies on catching an exception, and [exceptions are expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891217/how-expensive-are-exceptions-in-c). This should not be a problem if you are awaiting tokens sporadically, but in case you are awaiting tokens in tight loops, you may want to include in your project a cheap awaiter for `CancellationToken`s, as described in [this article](https://medium.com/@cilliemalan/how-to-await-a-cancellation-token-in-c-cbfc88f28fa2). It will allow you to do this:

```
await cts.Token;
```

---

**Alternative:** The exception can be suppressed also with this trick:

```
await Task.WhenAny(Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cts.Token));
```

Using the `Task.WhenAny` for the purpose of suppressing exceptions has some implications regarding the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509158/taskcanceledexception-when-calling-task-delay-with-a-cancellationtoken-in-an-key/59300076#59300076). It doesn't affect this case though (the event is not triggered).

Comment: the comment about the UnobservedTaskException is valid in general, but the link mentions it does not triggered for the *canceled* task.

Answer (score 1):

This code can be used to wait for a cancellation event without blocking the thread.

.NET6 version can be really simple and allows await to be cancellable

```
public async Task Run(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Simplification for the sake of example
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    
    var waitForStop = new TaskCompletionSource(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
    // IHostApplicationLifetime event can be used instead of `cts.Token`
    CancellationTokenRegistration registration = cts.Token.Register(() => waitForStop.SetResult());
    await using var _ = registration.ConfigureAwait(false);
    
    await waitForStop.Task.WaitAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

The `TaskCanceledException` won't be thrown because of the `cts.Cancel()` call. It will allow to do something (e.g. graceful shutdown) before leaving the method. However if cancellation requested for `cancellationToken` it will throw the `TaskCanceledException` as expected.

In case the developer needs to return the result:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

var waitForStop = new TaskCompletionSource<bool?>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
cts.Token.Register(obj =>
{
    var tcs = (TaskCompletionSource<bool?>)obj!;
    tcs.TrySetResult(true);
}, waitForStop);

var result = await waitForStop.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
```