# High cpu usage Windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, filesystemwatcher

Relatively new to c#. I made a windows form that monitors for changes to a change in a file. The program takes up 30% of my CPU and I would like to make it run a little lighter. After running the diagnostic session, I can see that Run() is using almost half of the program's resources. Is there a way I can optimize this?

```
static void Run()
{
    using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
    {
        watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(path);

        watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
        watcher.Renamed += OnRenamed;

        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Debug.WriteLine("Running Reader");
        while (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested) ;
    }
}
```

Here is my CPU usage.

[CPU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7W10.png)

My script to close the thread is also pretty heavy using almost 30%

```
static CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

private async void buttonRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonRun.Enabled = false; // Disable the button to prevent multiple clicks

    listBoxStatus.Items.Add($"Line Reader Started! \t Time: {DateTime.Now}");
    listBoxStatus.Items.Add("");

    status = "Running";
    statusApplier();

    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            LogApplicationStart();
            LoadComparisonFileLines();
            Run();
        }, cts.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        listBoxStatus.Items.Add($"Task was cancelled! \t Time: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // Catch any other exceptions
    {
        listBoxStatus.Items.Add($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        cts.Dispose(); // Dispose the CancellationTokenSource
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); // Reset the token source
        buttonRun.Enabled = true; // Enable the button after the task is completed or if an error occurs

        if (listBoxStatus.Items.Count > 0 && listBoxStatus.Items[listBoxStatus.Items.Count - 1].ToString().Contains("Change"))
        {
            listBoxStatus.Items.Add("");
        }

        listBoxStatus.Items.Add($"Line Reader Ended! \t Time: {DateTime.Now}");
        listBoxStatus.Items.Add("");

        status = "Stopped";
        statusApplier();

        LogApplicationEnd();
    }
}

private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cts.Cancel(); // Cancel the task
}
```

I greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks

I do not know how to use FileSystemWatcher more efficiently than I am already using it

Comment: Your while loop is constantly running.  Try adding a sleep in the loop and see if you usage goes down :  while (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested) ;   If the issue is the while loop than we can try better fixes.

Comment: That's called a tight loop and it's an anti pattern. I really don't think you need it at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait for request of CancellationToken cancellation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39942804/wait-for-request-of-cancellationtoken-cancellation)

Comment: You need to stop the thread, not just loop endlessly. Either `Wait` on the cancellation token, or better: just return out of that function, and use some other signalling mechanism that the watcher should be taken down.

Comment: You don't even need the CancellationToken  if you store the FSW object in a *field* and treat it like any other component. In fact, an FSW inherits from Component and can be added to any form through the designer. When `Stop` is clicked, just deactivate the FSW instance

Comment: Your CPU usage is better described as _somewhat over 25%_. I'm guessing you have a 4-core system. On a 2-core system, it would be somewhat over 50%. On a one core system, that tight `while` loop would suck the life out of your box, making it look hung. FSWs date from the days of 1-core systems; they are naturally asynchronous and don't require _polling_.

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about the **static* cancellationTokenSouce. Can you guarantee that there can only be one instance of your form? And sure that this will never change in the future?

Comment: A basic reviewing of any online tutorial on how to use `FileSystemWatcher` would have shown you that this is completely unnecessary. Why didn't you use such a tutorial instead of posting this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit causing high CPU usage is the while loop, and in fact, there should not be such an almost endless empty loop in the program.

The simplest solution for your code is to replace this loop with

```
cts.WaitHandle.WaitOne();
```

But there is another issue with your code. Your logic is to use one button to start watching and another button to stop it, so you should put the `finally` part and the part that disposes the `FileSystemWatcher` in the callback of the stop button. This `CancellationTokenSource` is redundancy.

Comment: Thanks a ton. That brought me down to 0% CPU usage. Actually huge improvement and I learned about busy waiting. Thanks again.

Comment: Read the comments on the original post, you really don't need the cancelation token at all