# Problem with cancelling the task in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have made an web application in ASP.NET. When on VideoDetails.cshtml page I click 'Anuluj' (cancel) button I have to cancel video starting and then there is back sequence started. But after second cancel button click it should stop as well, but instead of stopping I have an error thrown 'A task was cancelled.'.

Unfortunately it's not a syntax error but a logical one that I cannot handle myself.

GitHub repository: https://github.com/predond/NazcaWeb

Please take a look on the project and help me solve that issue.
Further discussion can be hold in GitHub discussion panel (more answers), how you like.

The error always shows up on line 'await Task.Delay(750, returnCancellationToken);' (246) in file IRC.cs after cancelling the token.

In order to run the project you have to read README file :)

And also if you could, by the way, review my code, I will be grateful, because I'm quite new to web applications and ASP.NET.

Comment: That's correct, when you cancel a task, an exception is thrown. You can catch that exception tough. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation

Comment: But I have checked before that place within if statement 'IsCancellationPending' and wrote break clause so it should've work. It there was a cancellation before that line it should break the loop. Am I not right?

Comment: True, the token is just a way to notify whatever is happening in the task that the task should return ASAP. So you can gracefully do some cleanup before returning. I am starting to doubt the origin of the exception. Do you somewhere use the token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()? Also, can you make a small example, not many people feel like digging through an entire repository. :)

Comment: No, I'm not using the token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() function anywhere. Also what kind of example would you like me to do? What should be in it? What code should it contains?

Comment: You just need to handle that OperationCancelledException, it is used for control flow, to notify client code that operation was cancelled, that's it. Despite of you check for cancellation request, it just happened in another point of execution, you did not work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. When you pass the cancellationtoken to the Task.Delay it throws an exception when the token is cancelled.

You can reproduce the problem with the following example.

```
void Start()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(2500);
    MyWorker(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
}

async Task MyWorker(CancellationToken token)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    try
    {

        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}, Tick");
            await Task.Delay(1000, token);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine($"{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}, Cancelled");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}, Exception, {ex.ToString()}");
    }
}
```

This will give the following output. So you can see that the delay is being canceled, but also an exception is thrown.

```
0, Tick
1018, Tick
2023, Tick
2536, Exception, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

If you don't pass the token to the delay, this is the output. So you can see the delay wasn't cancelled, and no exception was thrown. But the task did end gracefully.

```
0, Tick
1010, Tick
2027, Tick
3035, Cancelled
```

Here is some more info on how to fix this problem:

- [TaskCanceledException when calling Task.Delay with a CancellationToken in an keyboard event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509158/taskcanceledexception-when-calling-task-delay-with-a-cancellationtoken-in-an-key)

Comment: Of course, in production code, this should be done differently. It's just a minimalistic example to isolate the problem and do some testing. The task status after it has returned would be `RanToCompletion`.

Comment: Yeah, just highlighted points to regard. Removed previous comment. Task itself would be in different states, it might be important.

Comment: It would be nice if the caller knew that the task was cancelled. Now it looks like the task has completed, when in reality certain things were skipped because of the cancellation. My guess is that this is the reason why, normally, an exception is thrown. Just to let the caller know something is up and has to handle accordingly.

Comment: Thanks you very much. It works simply for adding ContinueWith function to Delay. It's the only error that may happen in that context - TaskCancelledException - so it's okay for use. I'll open two more questions about that repository (new features to add), so I hope you'll help me with them as well :)