# Try{}Catch optimization?

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization, try-catch, game-engine

I have a question about best practices regarding exceptions.  This weekend, I was working on my little game, and I found myself wondering if it's best to use IF or a TRY to validate NULL...  Here are the two variants of a same function:

This is my code using an IF

```
//Using IF
void ParseGamePad() {
    GamePadData pad = GamePad.GetDate(0);
    foreach(var btn in Enum.GetValues(GamePad.BUTTONS)) {
        if(myArray.ContainsKey(btn))
            if(myArray[btn]!=null)
                myArray[btn](); //Execute function reference in array
    }
    return;
}
```

Here's what the code is like with a `Try{}Catch`

```
//Using TRY
void ParseGamePad() {
    GamePadData pad = GamePad.GetDate(0);
    foreach(var btn in Enum.GetValues(GamePad.BUTTONS)) {
        try {
            myArray[btn](); //Execute function reference in array
        } catch(System.Exception e) {
            // Nothing to do here
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

The way I figure it, the `IF` block is quicker than the `TRY` block when the element doesn't exist in the array, whereas the `TRY` is quicker when the element exists, but slower when an Exception is caught.

What would you guys do?

PS: This project is on an embedded system, so CPU and RAM are a factor.

Comment: what type is `myArray`?

Comment: is myArray a Dictionary? (because an array doesn't have a method ContainsKey)

Comment: yes, it is something like `Dictionary<GamePad.BUTTONS, func_call>` where func_call is a delegate function reference.

Comment: if an exception is thrown, then .Net needs to start unwraping the stack, which takes about a hour... never use exception for bussiness logic, unless it's some sort of a catastrophic bussiness error, and even that rarely makes sense...

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes guys, I'll know not to ask questions 'round here anymore :)

Comment: @SsJVasto I really don't get the down votes, it's a perfectly valid question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If myArray is a Dictionary as I suspect, you can use TryGetValue.

Catching an exception is not a good solution in this case.

The first option has a (very) slight problem, because you're looking for the item twice, so TryGetValue is what I would use.
(If myArray is a Dictionary, then myArray is not a good name.)

Comment: The actual name is
Dictionary<GamePad.BUTTONS, onBtnPress> buttonPress_DelegateCalls;

Answer (score 5):

Do not use exceptions for program flow - they are meant to catch *exceptional* cases.  If `myArray[btn]` *should never be null* then throwing an exception when it *is* would be fine, but catching it to see if it is null is not a best practice (plus, catching `Exception` would cover *a lot* of possible conditions, not just when the value is `null` or not found).

As far as performance goes, checking an object for null should be *extremely* cheap, so I would not expect any significant performance difference in the normal case.

You could reduce the number of index lookups by two (which *could* make a significant performance improvement) by using `TryGetValue`:

```
foreach(var btn in Enum.GetValues(GamePad.BUTTONS)) {
    Action<Button> func;   // Guessing on the type here
    bool found = myArray.TryGetValue(btn, out func);
    if(found && func != null)
        func(); //Execute function reference in array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't rely on `Exceptions` as a proper flow for your system, as they will have performance effects. As null checks are a chearp an exception which may propogate up the call chain (which may take a while depending on your stack depth), you should go with the nullity check.

I would also say that `Exceptions` should be kept for unexpected behavior. You might decide that a `Dictionary` holding a null value is exceptional behavior in your program, and that's fine, as it is opinion based. I would definitely advised against it.

You should go ahead and check [How expensive are exceptions in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891217/how-expensive-are-exceptions-in-c) for excellent links on exceptions and performance.

Answer (score 1):

At least, I would not catch `Exception` but a more special exception type.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have the actual code at hand right now, but the exception caught is `System.Collections.Generic::KeyNotFoundException`