# Type checking or exceptions for text file parsing?

Tags: c#, parsing, error-handling, text-files

Exceptions are expensive, so I would think they would get the no vote in my case. I have a CSV file, with *n* columns on each row, all rows share the only record layout in the file.

I read the file, converting each row to an object, and perform various sums and counts on the entire collection of objects, with no interim operations, and then write an output file for my results. Yes, this is sort of a homework question, but my question is not their question.

I reckon if I do a type check for each column from the input file, build a collection of descriptions for each error, and then report on those errors, it would be much more efficient than if I try and catch when I parse/convert/etc. for each column.

That could be umpteen exceptions per input row, where text is quite easy to type check. An integer is a string with all it's characters in the string "0123456789", and if the destination type is not so simple, like, "OK", for an enum member, then I can `TryCast`, and get one exception, and include its message in the error descriptions for that row.

This is all even simpler if I must just write out invalid rows, with no explanation. Is this a sane approach?

Comment: The main concern should probably not be performance. For starters, the true cost of an exception [is not at all an easy thing to pin down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891217/how-expensive-are-exceptions-in-c). Even when it is your concern, a realistic question would be "just how invalid do you expect your input to be, and why does it matter if you're fast if you ultimately won't be able to process your input anyway"? Instead, design concerns should probably be leading.

Comment: _"If you ever get to the point where exceptions are significantly hurting your performance, you have problems in terms of your use of exceptions beyond just the performance."_ http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/exceptions2.html

Comment: I like to think no matter how invalid I expect my input to be, if an exception is significantly more expensive than using type checking per column (of course all columns together). Of course if the files are processed overnight or something, I'd be happy with exceptions, but when they are the payload of a service call, I'd want to pay more attention to the cost of error checking, or not checking.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That is my argument (academic question) from the start.

Comment: But surely it's the client who's providing the invalid input who'd be significantly affected by slow processing speed of said invalid input? It would be folly to optimize for this case rather than to focus on the happy path first. (Unless checking the file for problems *is* the main purpose of your service, of course.) The only reason I can think of to optimize error handling performance is security: malicious clients could use pathologically slow processing as a DOS attack. But you'd have to be *really* slow for that to matter. (And you want to measure that, not reason about it.)

Comment: Everyone, I did say (sorry, in a comment) this was a more academic (homework) question, where I know not the performance constraints, and neither any requirements beyond good error handling. I am very experienced (20 years), but not with this type of thing. In the workplace, I was always able to just discard the offending row at the first exception.

Comment: Academic questions are not a good fit for Stack Overflow, which is mainly concerned with solving actual, practical problems that do have constraints. Yes, you could check exceptions, yes, you could also parse conditionally. With no further constraints, I'd go for exceptions simply because it's easier to write. But I don't think that makes for a very good answer.