# Is throwing an Exception bad practice when returning error messages from WebApi to Client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, asp.net-core-webapi

Currently my WebApi throws an exception in order to display a message on the client side if any error occurred. This has proven convenient because I can wrap the exception in a `BadRequest()` response and it's nicely handled on the client side. 
I'm just wondering if this bad practice and weather I should be returning an object with an error flag + message or something like that instead. I would then have to change my client side code to deal with this...

Ex.
Api

```cs
[HttpPost("Login")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync([FromBody]LoginJS credentials)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _accountRepository.AuthenticateAsync(credentials.Username, credentials.Password);

                if (result.Success)
                    return Ok(result);
                else
                    return BadRequest("Login Failed!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

```cs
public async Task<AuthenticationResponse> AuthenticateAsync(string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    var emailVerified = await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user);
                    if (!emailVerified)
                        throw new Exception("Email Address has not yet been verified!");

                    var signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false, false);
                    if (signInResult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

                        if (!roles.Any())
                            throw new Exception("Sorry your account has not been setup yet.");

                        var authenticationResponse = await GenerateTokenAsync(user, roles.ToList());

                        return authenticationResponse;
                    }                       
                }

                throw new Exception("Login Failed!");

                //IS THIS THE BETTER WAY?
                //return new AuthenticationResponse
                //{
                //    Errors = new[] { "Login Failed" }
                //};
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(e.Message);
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions should be exceptional. This particular case is not exceptional. Exceptions can be costly from a performance point of view. Here is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891217/how-expensive-are-exceptions-in-c) that addresses this.

Returning the `AuthenticationResponse` in your example is a preferred approach. You can also check out the `TryXXX` pattern which is likely not useful here given your method is async.