# Possibly redundant use of Task.FromResult

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency

Section 10.2 within [Concurrency in .NET](https://www.manning.com/books/concurrency-in-dot-net) provides the following listing for an `Otherwise` task combinator:

```
public static Task<T> Otherwise<T>(this Task<T> task, Func<Task<T>> orTask) =>
    task.ContinueWith(async innerTask =>
    {
        if (innerTask.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted) return await orTask();
        return await Task.FromResult<T>(innerTask.Result);
    }).Unwrap();
```

(Confusingly, within the printed book, `Otherwise` is marked as `async` which fails to compile; however, not in the [GH listing](https://github.com/rikace/fConcBook/blob/3e6cf3126a6484a90a0a451e22fd68df6df8921b/Common/Functional.cs/Concurrency/AsyncEx.cs#L32-L37) which compiles without issue)

My "understanding" is that if the anonymous continuation is called, it would suggest that the supplied `innerTask` has completed by that point, successfully or otherwise.

Assuming successful, it would also suggest that `innerTask.Result` would already be determined with no synchronous waiting required upon calling that member property.

On the *mild* assumption that above is sensible... **What possible benefit is there from using `return await Task.FromResult<T>(innerTask.Result)` as opposed to just `return innerTask.Result`?** (the latter of which also compiles).

Unless I'm missing something (quite likely)... It feels overly verbose.

---

**Update:**

Thank you to everyone who has contributed; I never anticipated this would get as much feedback as it has!

At one point, I was concerned about a situation where `innerTask.Result` could raise an exception and how that would be dealt with by the 2x `return` approaches above.

From my own testing since, I can see that if `innerTask` was cancelled and, hence `innerTask.Status == TaskStatus.Cancelled`, the combinator implementation as given would permit the accessing of `innerTask.Result` which would then raise an `AggregateException`.

However, there is no difference in how this (or any other exception I imagine) would be treated by either `return` approach from within an `async` function.

Given this, and the information provided, it appears as though the former approach offers **nothing** over and above the latter. If anything, it (IMHO) obscurs the intention and has sent me down a (albeit illuminating) rabbit hole.

Comment: Regarding the comment about the _book-induced confusion_ above... This is the first time in ~300 pages where code is (seemingly?) incorrect. It has otherwise been a thoroughly interesting read outside of this.

Comment: No  there's no difference in exception handling. https://twitter.com/aSteveCleary/status/1155827537232220161?s=20&t=8AL8O_hH7uatbF7SRAZlJw

Comment: @StephenCleary... Using the vernacular of your tweet... **Is that still the case when `x` can raise an exception?** (as could be the case with `innerTask.Result`)

Comment: Yes, that is still the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What possible benefit is there from using `return await Task.FromResult<T>(innerTask.Result)` as opposed to just `return innerTask.Result`?

Absolutely zero benefit. That's the kind of code that your end up writing when you are struggling with a concept that you don't fully understand, and you reach to a version that compiles and works correctly. Your code might end up decorated with some useless cargo, which nonetheless is not harmful, so it might survive multiple code reviews and revisions.

Here is a better way to write the `Otherwise` extension method:

```
public static Task<T> Otherwise<T>(this Task<T> task, Func<Task<T>> onErrorTaskFactory)
{
    return task.ContinueWith(innerTask =>
    {
        if (innerTask.IsFaulted) return onErrorTaskFactory();
        return innerTask;
    }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach |
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
}
```

Notice that the continuation is not `async`, and it returns the `innerTask`, not its result. With this version you get these benefits:

1. In case the `onErrorTaskFactory()` returns a Task that also fails, and it contains more that one exceptions (think of passing a lambda that return `Task.WhenAll()`), all the errors will be propagated, not just the first one.
2. In case the `innerTask` is canceled, the cancellation will be propagated without an additional internal `try`/`catch`. Throwing and catching exceptions in C# is [quite expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891217/how-expensive-are-exceptions-in-c).
3. The code complies with the [CA2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008) guideline (*"Do not create tasks without passing a TaskScheduler"*).
4. The `onErrorTaskFactory` will be invoked synchronously on the thread that completed the `innerTask`, avoiding a thread-switch.

These benefits are not ground-breaking. I would evaluate the original implementation in the book as quite decent. It doesn't have any terrible bugs or inefficiencies.