# When and why to pass CancellationToken to TaskCompletionSource.SetCanceled?

Tags: c#, .net, task, cancellation-token

I don't understand what the `CancellationToken` parameter is for?

Passing the `CancellationToken` or not does not make any difference.

```
public async void test()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
    tcs.SetCanceled(cts.Token);

    try
    {
        await tcs.Task;
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.Message}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd assume to set the `CancellationToken` passed to the `TaskCanceledException` that's thrown by the task when awaited?

Comment: the point is this line: `tcs.SetCanceled(token);`, what's the difference between `tcs.SetCanceled(token);` and `tcs.SetCanceled();`?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama That is right, but I want to know in which cases it is useful?

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks, but my point is when to pass `CancellationToken` to `TaskCompletionSource.SetCanceled` api and why it is useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ProgrammingLlama suggested, that argument sets the [`CancellationToken` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operationcanceledexception.cancellationtoken?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#system-operationcanceledexception-cancellationtoken) on the exception that is raised when the task's result is observed. So the exception caught by `test` will have that property set to the cancellation token passed in.

I believe that the `CancellationToken` property was an attempt at being able to distinguish between different sources of cancellation; however, due to [linked cancellation tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-listen-for-multiple-cancellation-requests), this property is not useful in the general case.

Side notes:

- [Avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#avoid-async-void).
- Always dispose or cancel your `CancellationTokenSource`s.
- Use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`.

Comment: Two of the links in the answer include the URL parameter `WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058`. Does this parameter have any effect on the rendered web pages? If not, it might be better to remove it, to prevent tracking.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: It's a thing that MS set up a while back, to try to see who's providing links to the MS docs. 5000058 is me.

Comment: But the `IsCancellationRequested` property of `TaskCanceledException.CancellationToken`  is false in `catch` block, it is normal?

Comment: Here is a link [.net api proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30862) about the attempt of adding `void SetCanceled(CancellationToken)` api. it might be helpful.

Comment: @K1: It's probably false because the CTS was never cancelled. That's nor normal because the normal way to use `SetCanceled` is only after it's been cancelled (so the code would pass a cancelled token).

Answer (score 3):

The TPL is inconsistent regarding the state of the `CancellationToken` that is cancelling a `Task`. The [`Task.FromCanceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromcanceled) API requires the token to be canceled, otherwise it throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. On the contrary the [`TaskCompletionSource.SetCanceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource.setcanceled) API tolerates non-canceled tokens, allowing the paradoxical situation of a canceled task associated with a non-canceled token.

An additional complication is that sometimes a canceled task throws an [`OperationCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operationcanceledexception), and other times the derived class [`TaskCanceledException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception). I am pretty sure that if Microsoft could design the TPL again from scratch, they would clean up the API and avoid these inconsistencies.

I am adding as a bonus the information that it is possible to observe the `CancellationToken` associated with a `Task`, without incurring the [cost of exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891217/how-expensive-are-exceptions-in-c):

```
CancellationToken token = new TaskCanceledException(tcs.Task).CancellationToken;
```

Actually the `Task` class has a `CancellationToken` property, but it is inaccessible because [it is internal](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62006).