# Exceptions not being thrown for phonenumber

Tags: c#

This is my program to check for phoneno and name and throw an exception if they are not valid

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace exercise1
{
    public class Contact
    {
        string name;
        string phoneNo; 
       public Contact(string n, string p)
        {
            name = n;
            phoneNo = p; 
        }
        public string getName()
        {
            return name; 
        }
        public string getPhoneNo()
        {
            return phoneNo;
        }



    }
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
            String name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your phone number");
            String phoneNo = Console.ReadLine();
            Contact c = new Contact(name, phoneNo);

            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.getName()) || c.getName().Any(char.IsDigit))
                {
                    throw new InvalidName("Name not valid");
                }


                Console.WriteLine("Checked  name");

                // phoneNumber.All(char.IsDigit) -- LINQ expression 
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.getPhoneNo()) || c.getPhoneNo().Length != 10 || !(c.getPhoneNo().All(char.IsDigit)))
                {
                    throw new InvalidPhone("phone number not valid");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Phone number is valid");
                Console.WriteLine("Checked phoneno");
            }


            catch (InvalidName e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            catch (InvalidPhone ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            
          
            }
        }
    public class InvalidName : Exception
    {
        public InvalidName(string msg) : base(msg)
        {

        }
    }
    public class InvalidPhone : Exception
    {
        public InvalidPhone(string msg) : base(msg) { }
    }

}
```

I gave both invalid names like '3f' and phoneno like '23ds' but only the exception is thrown for the name, it doesn't even go to the next print statement after throwing the first exception

Comment: That is how try..catch works, when you have a try, as soon as it encounters an exception, and a matching catch, execution shifts to the catch block and once the catch block is complete then control comes out of the try..catch block. If you want separate messages to be printed for invalid name and phone have it in 2 try..catch blocks, one for the name and other for phone no.

Comment: Very OT: a method `getName()` sounds very Java-ish. In C# we would use a property: `public string Name { get; private set; }` - then you can use `c.Name`

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions are used when you have an erroneous situation.
When you throw an exception, then you are effectively saying that "things are bad, so there is no point continuing in this flow, you need to solve the errors first.".

So the throwing the exception will break the flow of your program.

And when you have it within a `try..catch` (the scope) then the flow will continue again from the `catch` point.

So, when we apply that to your code, then you must expect that at any point where you have a throw, that if it is executed, that nothing else below that point within the same scope will be executed, and only from the point of capture with the catch will execution continue.

So knowing that, then you are probably already able to realise that we shouldn't necessarily use exceptions in all cases where an error can occur (there are competing theories on this, so I won't go into more detail but you can google to find out more).

In fact, throwing an exception is a very expensive operation see also [How expensive are exceptions in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891217/how-expensive-are-exceptions-in-c)

So then when you have a situation like yours where you need to validate multiple inputs then you have two options on how to handle it in general.

1. You keep the flow as it is, and you accept that you will only ever deal with one error at a time.
   This tends to be better when you ask for 1 piece of input and validate it immediately being asking for the next piece of input.
2. You change the flow so that you record all the errors during a validation stage and then you inform the user of all the issues at the same time.

So if we apply method 1 to your code you end up with something like this;

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
    String name = Console.ReadLine();
    
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || name.Any(char.IsDigit))
    {
        throw new InvalidName("Name not valid");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Enter your phone number");
    String phoneNo = Console.ReadLine();
    // phoneNumber.All(char.IsDigit) -- LINQ expression 
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phoneNo) || phoneNo.Length != 10 || !(phoneNo.All(char.IsDigit)))
    {
        throw new InvalidPhone("phone number not valid");
    }   

    Contact c = new Contact(name, phoneNo);
}
catch (InvalidName e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
catch (InvalidPhone ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

You will also notice, that the code performs the validation on the inputted data and only creates the class at the end.  It is a good idea to only create the class with data that you know is valid.  It will also be more efficient (not that you will notice in such a simple program).

If we apply method 2 then we end up with something like this.

```
List<string> errors = new List<string>();

Console.WriteLine("Enter your name");
String name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter your phone number");
String phoneNo = Console.ReadLine();

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) || name.Any(char.IsDigit))
{
    errors.Add("Name not valid");
}   
    
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phoneNo) || phoneNo.Length != 10 || !(phoneNo.All(char.IsDigit)))
{
    errors.Add("phone number not valid");
}   

if(errors.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The following errors occured");
    foreach(string err in errors)
        Console.WriteLine(err);
        
    //Optional, you could throw a ValidationFailed exception here as well or instead of outputting the data if you want to inform/interrupt the upstream flow.
}
else
{
    Contact c = new Contact(name, phoneNo);
}
```

You can also expand this to check and report each validation part separately.  This way you can give the user more details information about the exact error.  For example;

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phoneNo) 
{
    errors.Add("Phone number cannot be empty or null.");
}   
else
{
    if(phoneNo.Length != 10)
        errors.Add("Phone number must be 10 digits.");

    if(!(phoneNo.All(char.IsDigit)))
        errors.Add("Phone number can only contain numbers");
}
```

In such cases if often becomes better to then more the validation into separate methods, or even dedicated classes or to use 3pp validation handling libraries.